# How to create an element after other jquery

Tags: jquery

I have an array an elements. They have similar id:

```
Step2_Visits_0__CountryCode
Step2_Visits_1__CountryCode
Step2_Visits_2__CountryCode
Step2_Visits_3__CountryCode
Step2_Visits_4__CountryCode
```

This array names as "visitCountries".

I use "loop for" and append after each element tag .

For example:

```
for(var i=0; i < 20; i++) {
$(visitCountries[i].id).append("<a id=editCountryItemIcon[" + i + "]" 
    + "style=\"vertical-align: bottom;\"" 
    + "class=\"editLineItemLink\""); 
}
```

But it doesn't work. Please,help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the main problem will be that jQuery uses a hash (`#`) to prefix an id whn using it as a selector, so change your code to:

```
for(var i=0; i < 20; i++) {
    $('#' + visitCountries[i].id).....
```

In addition there are 2 more issues with your code;

1. You never close the `<a>` element you're appending, so nothing will display onscreen. Put another way, the element you're trying to append would look like this in HTML

   `<a id=editCountryItemIcon[0] style="vertical-align: bottom;" class="editLineItemLink"`

   So make sure you also append `>Some text</a>`
2. In order for a link to be clickabble, it needs an `href` attribute. The usual convention is to add `href="#"` if you have nowhere you actually want the link to navigate to (eg, if its handled by javascript).
3. There is no spaces before the attribute names

So all in all, the final code should probably look something like:

```
var visitCountries = ["Step2_Visits_0__CountryCode","Step2_Visits_1__CountryCode","Step2_Visits_2__CountryCode","Step2_Visits_3__CountryCode","Step2_Visits_4__CountryCode"];
for(var i=0; i < 20; i++) {
$('#' + visitCountries[i]).append("<a href=\"#\" id=editCountryItemIcon[" + i + "]" 
    + " style=\"vertical-align: bottom;\"" 
    + " class=\"editLineItemLink\">Link</a>"); 
}
```

Here's a live example demonstrating working code: http://jsfiddle.net/Lx93w/

Comment: It doesn't work. I see id, when write without '#'. But he don't append html to this element.

Comment: @user1129783 - See update. And please don't use "not working" - describe *what* is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
for(var i=0; i < 20; i++) {
$(visitCountries[i].id).append("<a id=\"#editCountryItemIcon[" + i + "]\"" 
    + " style=\"vertical-align: bottom;\"" 
    + " class=\"editLineItemLink\""); 
}
```

Don't forget the spaces before other attributes, and enclosing the id attribute in quotes. Also, you should use # as @Jamlec mentioned.